# Kubernetes connect Psycopg2 to GCP Postgres with SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, kubernetes-secrets

I am stuck trying to connect to a google managed postgres instance from my Kubernetes pod.

My pod and secret yaml looks like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db_secret
stringData:
  CLIENT_KEY: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----3eFQ==-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  CLIENT_CERT: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----iiEooYXOze-----END CERTIFICATE-----
  SERVER_CA: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----M9+99XZx4=-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
volumeMounts:
                    - mountPath: /certs
                      name: db-ssl-certs
                      readOnly: true
            volumes:
              - name: db-ssl-certs
                secret:
                  secretName: db_secret
                  items:
                    - key: CLIENT_KEY
                      path: client-key.key
                    - key: CLIENT_CERT
                      path: client-cert.crt
                    - key: SERVER_CA
                      path: server-ca.crt
```

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres', user='postgres', host='X.X.X.X', port='5432', sslmode='verify-ca', sslrootcert='server-ca.crt', sslcert='client-cert.crt', sslkey='client-key.key')
```

When I try to connect with the instance like above, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not read root certificate file "server-ca.crt": no certificate or crl found
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The internal newlines in the encoded string are not optional to PostgreSQL.  I'm not familiar with this "secrets" infrastructure, when you cat the resulting file is it all one line?

Comment: @jjanes Yes. The output is a single line.

Comment: @jjanes Adding the new lines fixed it. You can make your comment an answer and let me accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Sam Is your issue resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution .

Comment: @Rameshkollisetty What I did was to make sure I copied the certificate files as is to the secret file faith newlines kept. I used the |- literal style to ensure the newlines are kept consistent.

Comment: @Sam please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that it would be helpful for other community members for reference.